# Mongoose updateMany depending old values

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose and nodejs so maybe my question isn't clear.

I'm using `mongoose` and  I have the following Model:

```
const numberSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     n: {
          type: Number,
          required: true
     },
     created_at: {
         type: Date,
         default: Date.now()
     }
 });
```

I need to update all documents with adding `+1` for each `n` property

```
const result = await Number.updateMany(
    {}, 
    { n: **{how_to_access_current_value}** + 1 },
    { multi: true} 
);
```

How can I access the current value of `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
var newN = 1;
const result = await Number.updateMany(
    {}, 
    { $inc: { n: newN }},
    { multi: true } 
);
```

Comment: That increment is a good solution thanks ;)  But if n was a variable? sometimes it can be 1 or 2 or maybe -1 how can I do this?

Comment: Just have the variable in place of 1.

Comment: Thanks juste another question if the operator is a variable too? '+', '-', '*' or '/'

Comment: No it does only increment .

Comment: how can I achieve the operator variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203425/discussion-between-hbamithkumara-and-y-jrb).